# Flutter Redux Middleware

Tags: redux, dart, flutter

I'm completely new to redux and it's beginning to make sense. I'm trying to use the middleware to keep the reducer a pure function but it's giving me an error I don't understand. I'm following the flutter architecture samples for redux

```
void main() {
  final store = Store<AppState>(
    appReducer,
    initialState: AppState.loading(),
    middleware: createStoreFlashCardsMiddleware(),
  );
  runApp(new MyApp(store));
}
```

//the middleware

```
List<Middleware<AppState>> createStoreFlashCardsMiddleware() {
  final loadFlashCards = _createLoadFlashCardsMiddleware();
  final saveFlashCards = _createSaveFlashCardsMiddleWare();

  return [
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, FetchFlashCardsAction>(loadFlashCards),
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, AddFlashCardAction>(saveFlashCards),
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, ClearCompletedAction>(saveFlashCards),
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, ToggleAllAction>(saveFlashCards),
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, UpdateFlashCardAction>(saveFlashCards),
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, FetchCardsSucceededAction>(saveFlashCards),
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, DeleteFlashCardAction>(saveFlashCards),
  ];
}

Middleware<AppState> _createSaveFlashCardsMiddleWare() {
  return (Store store, action, NextDispatcher next) async {
  // YOUR LOGIC HERE
  // After you do whatever logic you need to do,
  // call this Redux built-in method,
  // It continues the redux cycle.
  next(action);
  };
}

Middleware<AppState> _createLoadFlashCardsMiddleware() {
  return (Store store, action, NextDispatcher next) async {
  next(action);
  };
}
```

The error is:

```
error: The argument type 'List<(Store<AppState>, dynamic, (dynamic) → void) → void> (C:\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\list.dart)' can't be assigned to
the parameter type 'List<(Store<AppState>, dynamic, (dynamic) → void) → void> (C:\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\list.dart)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [line])
```

Comment: Can you share the code of _createLoadFlashCardsMiddleware and _createSaveFlashCardsMiddleWare()?

Comment: You don't have by any chance relative imports in `lib/main.dart` (the ones that don't start with `import 'package: ...` or `import 'dart:...`? See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33076

Comment: I included the functions but they're empty as of now.

Comment: I removed main outside of the lib (didn't know it was recommended) but all the imports seem to be import 'package:'

Comment: It seems that I can't run your minimum sample code. Could you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also are you using any [redux plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/redux)?